# DOM manipulation done in compile phase runs once, and propagate always - what this means

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I'm reading [this article](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications#10-2-the-compile-cycle) about angular performance optimization and there is the following passage there:

> Directive's compile functions run before scope is attached and are the
>   perfect place to run any DOM manipulations (binding events for
>   example). The important thing to recognize from a performance point of
>   view, is that the element and attributes passed into the compile
>   function represent the raw html template, before any of angular's
>   changes have been made. What this means in practice is that DOM
>   manipulation done here, will run once, and propagate always. Another
>   important point that is frequently glossed over is the difference
>   between prelink and postlink. In short, prelinks run from the outside
>   in, while postlinks run from the inside out. As such, prelinks offer a
>   slight performance boost, as they prevent the inner directives from
>   running a second digest cycle when the parent modifies scope in the
>   prelink. However, child DOM may not yet be available.

I can't understand these two parts and how I can use it to boost performance:

> What this means in practice is that DOM
>   manipulation done here, will run once, and propagate always.

And this

> prelinks offer a
>   slight performance boost, as they prevent the inner directives from
>   running a second digest cycle when the parent modifies scope in the
>   prelink

I'd appreciate if anyone could elobarate on that.

Answer (score 8):

> What this means in practice is that DOM manipulation done here, will
>   run once, and propagate always.

### Run Once?

This is referring to the AngularJS compilation process. As the AngularJS compiler traverses the DOM, it will compile the directives that it finds exactly once.

### DOM Manipulation?

When a directive's compile function is called, there is an opportunity to modify the HTML ahead of the AngularJS compiler.

### Propagate Always?

This just means that the final DOM is determined at the end of the compilation process.

### Example

To hit the point home, consider the following example:

```
<div directive1> <!-- grandparent -->
    <div directive2>  <!-- parent -->
         <div directive3> <!-- child -->
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The AngularJS compiler will visit the grandparent first, then the parent, and finally the child.

There are three opportunities to modify the HTML ahead of angular compilation:

1. directive1 compile function
2. directive2 compile function
3. directive3 compile function

Now consider how the final HTML changes when we manipulate the DOM in the compile function for directive1:

When the directive1's compile function is called:

```
<div directive1> <!-- compiled -->
    <div directive2>  <!-- not compiled -->
         <div directive3> <!-- not compiled -->
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the compile function, let's change the HTML ahead of the AngularJS compiler:

```
app.directive('directive1', function() {
     restrict: 'A',
     compile: function($element, $attr) {
         // $element points to directive1 element
         $element.html('<div directive4></div>');
     }
});
```

After the compile function for directive1 is called:

```
<div directive1> <!-- compiled -->
    <div directive4>  <!-- not compiled -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the DOM changes so that directive2 and directive3 no longer exist and directive4 is next in line to be compiled.

> prelinks offer a slight performance boost, as they prevent the inner
>   directives from running a second digest cycle when the parent modifies
>   scope in the prelink

Hmm. This makes no sense to me. As I understand it, the digest phase happens after the pre-link and post-link phases. I'm not sure how modifying scope in pre-link or post-link phases will impact the digest cycle.

The following image has been referenced from this article:
http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-js-demystifying-directives

[image]

Comment: thanks for your elaborate answer, I've upvoted it. Unfortunately, everything you've mentioned I already know and I've even distilled the main points of compilation and linking phases [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437692/does-angular-create-new-dom-tree-after-compile-phase-or-continue-working-with-or/29445520#29445520). It would be great if you could maybe show how what you've described is relevent to the perfomance boost mentioned in the article. Thanks