# does angular create new DOM tree after compile phase or continue working with original modified DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I have the following HTML:

```
<div dir-parent>
    <div dir-child1></div>
</div>
```

During compilation phase directive `dirParent` will receive template DOM element that has inside of it the `div` with a `dirChild1` directive. If I don't change this `html` inside `dirParent`'s compile function, then compile function is then called for `dirChild1` directive. However, if I remove `<div dir-child1="" some-child1-attr></div>` inside `dirParent`'s compile function, then angular continues processing this *modified* DOM that no longer has a div with `dir-child1` directive and so compile function for `dir-child1` directive is never executed.

I assumed that once angular is done executing compile functions it builds new DOM from `html` *modified* during compile functions. Is this assumption correct? This *modified* DOM seems to be referred as *instance* DOM elements and is available during `pre-link` phase, so I assume that this is the phase when angular constructs instance elements DOM tree.

Comment: What do you mean by _ready_? You already know that the element is created in step 1. It can be modified in any of the following steps.

Comment: I've completely rewritten my question to make more clear what I'm asking

Comment: @zeroflagL, investigated the matter, please see my answer if interested.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you want to know. Anyway, Angular itself only creates DOM nodes when a directive specifies a template. In that case it can even replace existing nodes, if a directive defines `replace: true`. Any other DOM manipulation that may occur is performed by directives themselves.

Comment: @zeroflagL, right, but what you're saying is clearly stated in the manual. I'm investigating the internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent 3 hours investigating Angular's source code (it's written in so hard to read manner) and found the answer to my question. Angular doesn't distinguish between template and instance elements inside, it works with the same tree it has when it begins compiling. Here is the essence of the source code that demonstrates that:

```
var element = $("body");
compile(element)($rootScope);

function compile(DOMElementsTree) {
    var compositeLinkFn = compileNodes(DOMElementsTree);
    return function publicLinkFn(scope) {
        var $linkNode = DOMElementsTree;
        compositeLinkFn(scope, $linkNode);
        return $linkNode;
    }
}

function compileNodes(nodesList) {
    var linkFns = [];

    nodesList.forEach(function (node) {
        var nodeLinkFn = applyDirectivesToNode(node);
        var childNodes = nodesList.childNodes;
        var childLinkFn = !!childNodes.length ? compileNodes(childNodes) : null;
        if (nodeLinkFn || childLinkFn) {
            linkFns.push(i, nodeLinkFn, childLinkFn);
        }
    });

    return function compositeLinkFn(scope, nodeList) {
        linkFns.forEach(function (linkFn) {
            var nodeLinkFn = linkFn[1];
            var childNodeLinkFn = linkFn[2];

            if (nodeLinkFn) {
                nodeLinkFn(childLinkFn, scope, nodeList);
            } else if (childNodeLinkFn) {
                childLinkFn(scope, nodeList)
            }
        });
    }
}

function applyDirectivesToNode() {
    // this is where compile functions of all directives on a node are executed
}

function nodeLinkFn() {
    // here pre link and post link functions are executed
}

function childLinkFn() {
    // here pre link and post link functions are executed
}
```

You can see that `applyDirectivesToNode` which executes `compile` functions of a directive doesn't return any new DOM node, instead it modifies `DOMElementsTree` that it receives by references and `compositeLinkFn` continues working with this DOM instance.

Initially I had this piece of sample code in my question taking [from here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#how-directives-are-compiled):

```
var $compile = ...; // injected into your code
var scope = ...;
var parent = ...; // DOM element where the compiled template can be appended

var html = '<div ng-bind="exp"></div>';

// Step 1: parse HTML into DOM element
var template = angular.element(html);

// Step 2: compile the template
var linkFn = $compile(template);

// Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope.
var element = linkFn(scope);

// Step 4: Append to DOM (optional)
parent.appendChild(element);
```

So in this extract the last step deals with the result of the `publicLinkFn` function, namely `$linkNode` in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

The `DOM` element is indeed created during step1, however it is only available in the browser memory but not reflected in the actual page DOM.

Since the element has been created from Javascript (`var html = ...`) once it is compiled and linked, you need to put it back to the page using `append` so the user can actually see and interact with it.

**Update** I don't understand what you are asking exactly, but I don't think you will find an answer on StackOverflow. What you need is a forum or more lecture about the internal functionning of AngularJS. I highly recommend you to read this article: http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/

**Update2** From my understanding (and accoding to the article cited above), Angular will first compile the template from `dir-parent` and then compile its children *using that same template*. If you have modified this template during the top compile phase, for instance by removing `dir-child1`, then indeed there is nothing else to compile and Angular will then proceed with the `pre-link` and finally `post-link`.

Comment: Yeah, I see, thanks. The article you linked is a top level description while I'm interested in a deeper understanding. Occasionally I read angular.js source code to get a desired knowledge but this one is a bit tricky to understand. Thanks anyway, best!

Comment: Oh ok, well I am not experienced enough :-p but would also be interested by an answer if someone understands the question better than I do. However I still think that you should ask that on a dedicated forum, or even might ask an expert directly at some ng-conf/angular meetups

Comment: yeah, let's see if anyone gives an answer to this :)

Comment: This is not shadow DOM.

Comment: @floribon, I've completely rewritten my question to make more clear what I'm asking

Comment: @Maximus I've added more to my answer in case this helps, however I am still not sure I really get what troubles what, what you real question is :(

Comment: @zeroflagL thanks for the precision, indeed shadow dom is a different concept.

Comment: @floribon, investigated the matter, please see my answer if interested.